# Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.getParam')

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

React-native, react-navigation. I have a custom header, with a button, that I've extracted to another file. I can't seem to get access to the navigation object.

```
function SetNavOptions(title, navigation) {
    const { buttonStyle, iconStyle } = styles;
    return {
        headerBackground: (<LinearGradient
            colors={['#337ab7', '#265a88']}
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            start={[0, 0]}
            end={[0, 1]}
        />),
        headerTitleStyle: {
            color: 'white',
        },
        headerTitle: title,
        headerLeft: (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.getParam('mydrawer')} style={buttonStyle}>
                <View>
                    <Icon.FontAwesome
                        name='bars'
                        size={26}
                        style={iconStyle}
                    />
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
    };
}
```

And this is my screen where I set the navigationOptions variable:

```
export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

  static navigationOptions = SetNavOptions('Topics', this.navigation);

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({ mydrawer: this.openDrawer });
  }

  openDrawer = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('myDrawer');
  };

}
```

Running the code and clicking the button, I get 'undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.getParam'). What am I doing wrong? Also, is how I defined SetNavOptions() the best way to extract all of that? I'm new to react-native.

Comment: Where's your stack navigator?

Comment: Happy to post it, but it's just a standard createStackNavigator() that's then passed to a createBottomTabNavigator(). Are you saying that the navigationOptions should be defined there and not per screen?

Comment: Your component is not receiving the ```navigation```  prop (hence the error). ```createStackNavigator``` should take care of that

Comment: and yes, putting nav options there will save you a lot of heartache

Comment: `HomeScreen` is getting navigation. The `componentDidMount()` function completes without error. Is it that I'm trying to reference navigation from outside of a class function? Also, how can I set all the header options in `createBottomTabNavigator`? It's unclear from the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my `static navigationOptions` line was not correct in the `HomeScreen` class. It should be this instead:

`static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => SetNavOptions('Topics', navigation)`

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem, and `route.params.mydrawer` instead of `navigation.getParam('mydrawer')` solved the issue. Looks like there was an update with React Native router, because before it warked with `navigation.getParam`.

Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/64932908/11127383